# Date Format Converter Approach

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Date from my UI is in **dd/mm/yyyy** format.
Date in DB is **yyyy-mm-dd** format.
I need to convert the dates to and fro from UI to Database.

The DTO and Entity dates are of type  java.util.Date.
I'm using spring's **BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination)**, for setting properties of dto and entity to and fro.

I've got the following solutions:
 1. Implementing JPA AttributeConverter
 2. Using Custom Java Annotations
 3. Using a simple date format converter utility class.
What is the best approach for Date Format Converter.

My Technology Stack is:

1. jQuery
2. JDK 7
3. Spring 4
4. JPA

Comment: "Date in DB is yyyy-mm-dd format" - why is your database using a string to represent the date at all? Most databases have a date type... I suggest you use that, at which point you can stick to domain-specific types instead of converting to/from a specific format.

Comment: we are using sql server, it's just the date format, but the datatype is date.

Comment: If the data type is `Date` in the database, then you shouldn't be dealing with it as text - deal with it *as* a date. See `PreparedStatement.setDate` etc.

Comment: You have DATE in the database, and you persist a java.util.Date / java.sql.Date field into it. Formatting is utterly irrelevant to that process. Formatting is only relevant in your GUI

Comment: We are using jpa for CRUD operations. The date is not being saved when sent from the ui in dd/mm/yyyy format. But it saves when sent in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: JPA does not SEE any "format". It sees objects. Those objects are created by YOU. How do you expect people here to tell you what you've done wrong without posting the code that creates those objects?! Where is your debugging?

Answer (score 0):

JPA should automatically convert the date. To format it for displaying purposes use:

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use objects, not strings

No need to manipulate strings of date-time values. Instead use date-time objects. The objects have no “format”.

You say the date values are indeed stored in the database as a [SQL `DATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) type. So you should be retrieving this into Java as a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object if in [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or later, or as a [`java.sql.DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) if in earlier [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

Search Stack Overflow for how to use these object types with your technology stack. This has been covered *many* times already.